# displaying web view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am new in iPhone development and I want to perform a simple task with `UIWebView`. I just want to display an `URL` on a new view when i click on a button present in the root view controller. But when i do this i get an exception

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a
>   nil modal view controller on target .

Here is my code.

WebViewController.m (This is the view where i have kept the `UIWebView`)

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestobj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webview.delegate self];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:requestobj];
```

Comment: how you are invoking WebViewController?

Comment: post the code of your button method

Comment: -(IBAction)call:(id)sender
{   WebViewController *wv = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wv animated:YES];
    
}

Comment: in the root view controller i did navigation to the WebviewController on the event of button click.

Comment: chk your xib is the view outlet is connected to fileowner?

Comment: @Aman Are you talking about the delegate connected to the file owner? If yes then yes it is connected.

Comment: Check your self.navigationController should not be nil.

Comment: @paul no, i am talking about view outlet of your file owner in your xib

Comment: @Aman Yes it is connected

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

Well the error says you are trying to push a nil value.

**Things to check**

- Make sure the `WebViewcontroller` is initialised properly[it cannot be nil]
- Make sure the nib name is WebViewController
- Files owner has class name WebViewController

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you have defined the webview by the following. UIWebview is a subclass of UIView.

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;


NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```